# VSCode Cursive Font Spacing Issue

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code, themes, cursive

I tried using Petit Script Formal to get cursive font in vscode, however, the spacing between words and characters seems to be off and my cursor is always in the wrong spot.

[Here is an example of this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKbP4.png)

Comment: Could you add some more detail to your question, specifically which platform, and how you obtained the font? I’ll try to repro and diagnose, but need more info. I suspect a font bug.

Comment: @djangodude I have windows 10. I downloaded the font from google fonts and followed this guide: https://medium.com/@JeffHykin/how-to-get-cursive-fonts-in-vs-code-2018-without-operator-mono-220544fed93a

Answer (score 0):

Using the hotkeys `CTL + ,` or `CMD + ,` to get to settings. Open the settings as a JSON file and add

```
"editor.fontLigatures": true
```

This should fix the issue with the cursor.